# Android databinding click listener not working(work randomly)

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

My click listener are not working even if I check with a Toast inside of them, it use to work but after I made a couple of change in my viewModel it stop working, I can't figure out what went wrong. This happen in my detail activity only, but work on the recyclerview that call this detail activity via intent. I'm using Viewmodel, Livedata, databinding and Room. The recyclerview and the detail view are using the same viewmodel.

This is the code of my Detail activity:

```
class BuyDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var sharedViewModel: BuySharedViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    lateinit var buy: Buy

    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BuySharedViewModel::class.java)

    val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)
    sharedViewModel.allBuys.observe(this, Observer<List<Buy>> { buys ->
        buy = buys[position]
        val binding: com.example.drake.kunuk.databinding.ActivityBuyDetailBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, com.example.drake.kunuk.R.layout.activity_buy_detail)
        binding.buy = buy


        val agentNumber = buy.agentNumber
        bnvContactAgent.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_call -> {
                    val callNumberUri = Uri.parse("tel:$agentNumber")
                    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, callNumberUri)
                    startActivity(callIntent)
                }
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_sms -> {
                    val smsNumberUri = Uri.parse("sms:$agentNumber")
                    val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, smsNumberUri)
                    startActivity(smsIntent)
                }
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_email -> {
                    val uriText = "mailto:xxxxxxxx@gmail.com" +
                            "?subject=" + Uri.encode("I'm interested in $agentNumber") +
                            "&body=" + Uri.encode("Hello, ")

                    val uri = Uri.parse(uriText)

                    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                    sendIntent.data = uri
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"))
                }
            }
            false
        }

        // set animation duration via code, but preferable in your layout files by using the animation_duration attribute
        expandableTextView.setAnimationDuration(750L)

        // set interpolators for both expanding and collapsing animations
        expandableTextView.setInterpolator(OvershootInterpolator())

        // or set them separately
        expandableTextView.expandInterpolator = OvershootInterpolator()
        expandableTextView.collapseInterpolator = OvershootInterpolator()

        // toggle the ExpandableTextView
        buttonToggle.setOnClickListener {
            buttonToggle.setText(if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more else com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
            expandableTextView.toggle()
        }

        // but, you can also do the checks yourself
        buttonToggle.setOnClickListener {
            if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) {
                expandableTextView.collapse()
                buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more)
            } else {
                expandableTextView.expand()
                buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
            }
        }

        //Open photoView activity when clicked
        ivHouseDetail.setOnClickListener {
            applicationContext
                .startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        applicationContext,
                        ViewPagerActivity::class.java
                    )
                        .putExtra("imageList", buy.propertyImage)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                )
        }

    })


}


}
```

Here's my SharedViewmodel, use by both the fragment calling the detail activity and the detail activity.

```
class BuySharedViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val repository: BuyRepository
var allBuys: LiveData<List<Buy>>


init {
    val buyDao = KunukRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).buyDao()
    val buyRemote = BuyRemote()
    repository = BuyRepository.getInstance(buyDao , buyRemote)
    //Use async because it return a result
    viewModelScope.async { getAllBuys() }
    allBuys = buyDao.loadAllBuys()
}

private suspend fun getAllBuys() {
    repository.getBuys()

}
}
```

And finally this is the xml of the detail activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable name="buy" type="com.example.drake.kunuk.data.model.Buy"/>

</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bnvContactAgent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_contact_agent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

    <ScrollView
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bnvContactAgent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:context=".ui.buy.BuyDetailActivity">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
                    android:id="@+id/ivHouseDetail"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/house"
                    app:imageUrl="@{buy.propertyImage}"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      app:formatToUSD="@{buy.price}"
                      android:id="@+id/tvPriceDetail"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                      android:textSize="20sp"
                      tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivHouseDetail" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@{buy.address}"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvAddressDetail"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPriceDetail"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@{Integer.toString(buy.numberOfRoom)}"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvBedroom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddressDetail"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bed"
                    android:id="@+id/ivBedroom"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/bedroom_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvBedroom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddressDetail"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@{Integer.toString(buy.numberOfBath)}"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvBathroom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivBedroom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivBedroom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bathtub"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/bathroom_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvBathroom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddressDetail"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@{Integer.toString(buy.numberOfCar)}"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvGarage"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_garage"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/garage_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvGarage"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddressDetail"/>

            <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="281dp" tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDescTitle"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/tvDescTitle"
                      android:text="@string/description"
                      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textSize="18sp"
                      android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/expandableTextView"
                      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
            <at.blogc.android.views.ExpandableTextView
                    android:text="@{buy.propertyDesc}"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/expandableTextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    app:animation_duration="750"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDescTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonToggle"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:text="@string/more"
                    app:goneUnless="@{true}"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/expandableTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
            <TextView
                    app:photoCounter="@{buy.propertyImage}"
                    android:background="#99000000"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffafffff"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivHouseDetail"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="323dp" android:id="@+id/tvPhotoCounter"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code is my repository class, where I use the coroutines.

```
class BuyRepository (private val buyDao: BuyDao, private val buyRemote: BuyRemote) {
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)

companion object {
    //For singleton instantiation
    @Volatile private var instance: BuyRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(buyDao: BuyDao, buyRemote: BuyRemote) =
        instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: BuyRepository(buyDao, buyRemote)
                .also { instance = it}
        }
}


suspend fun getBuys(){
    refresh()
}

private suspend fun refresh(){
    val list = scope.async {buyRemote.loadBuys()}
    list.await().forEach { buy -> insert(buy) }
}


//@WorkerThread
private fun insert(buy: Buy) {
    buyDao.insertBuy(buy)
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // toggle the ExpandableTextView
    buttonToggle.setOnClickListener { // <- Set listener here
        buttonToggle.setText(if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more else com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
        expandableTextView.toggle()
    }

    // but, you can also do the checks yourself
    buttonToggle.setOnClickListener { // <- And overwritten here - seems bad
        if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) {
            expandableTextView.collapse()
            buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more)
        } else {
            expandableTextView.expand()
            buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
        }
    }
```

Looks to me like you're overwriting the click listener. So ... don't do that :)

Comment: Ok, I did that. It still not working. My modification were about "couroutines", I use them to fetch data from api and insert in a room database. And the app would use only the database as a single source of truth. Can misuses of coroutines be the cause?

Comment: Well, your post does not show any coroutines, so I can only go off what you posted. Without seeing more code, anything can be the cause. You said "it use to work but after I made a couple of change in my viewModel it stop working" - how about you undo those changes (you're using source control, right!?) and try again one step at a time?

Comment: I'm using git. Thanks for your help. I'm editing to add my repository class

Comment: I catch the erro, but don't know how to fix it. This line `//Use async because it return a result
    viewModelScope.async { getAllBuys() }` It said that defered result is never used. But when I use `launch` instead of async it crash, because when of the field  that should be save in database is null.

Comment: I noticed it work randomly, sometimes it works, sometimes not